# Freertos tasks context switching

Tags: c, freertos, rtos, esp-idf

Context switching as I understood it, is when a highier priority task becomes ready and the schedular immediately selects it to run saving the context of the previous task so it continues once this new high priority task is blocking.
So what happens when a task calls a blocking function `ex: vTaskDelay()` mid task, does context switching happens the same way as described or will the task start from the start.

Take this code for example

```
int i = 0;
while( c != EOF ){
     printf("%c",c);
     if( i == 10 ){vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); }
     i++;
}
```

Does the loop continue or start from i=0

Comment: It will continue, but it will never end since you never change `c` (assuming `c` is not `EOF` already when the loop starts).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo True but i just came up with an example from the top of my head it should be while((c = fgetc(`some_file`)) != EOF)....

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does not matter. Imagine `while(1)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so what happens when a task calls a blocking function ex: vTaskDelay()

`vTaskDelay()` **is not blocking**. The task is put into the BLOCKED state and control is passed to another task and your processor will execute other tasks. The control is passed back to the task at some point when delay passes.

> Context switching as I understood it, is when a highier priority task
> becomes ready

It you do not enable round-robin in the freeRTOS configuration the control will only passed to another task when you allow it (by [for example] calling `vTaskDelay()` function, semaphore, queue etc functions). *free**RTOS*** is not like big OSes.

> mid task, does context switching happens the same way as described or
> will the task start from the start.

The execution will continue from from the next statement after the `vTaskDelay()`.

Comment: So a task that is approximated to take some time, a delay is the solution so it doesnt starve the cpu? Or is there a better workflow. Since im working with the esp-idf the watchdog gets triggered if starvation occurs

Comment: Yes delay in RTOS is something different than in the arduino and it does not starve the CPU. The control is taken from the task and it is not given back until the delay passes. The rest of the program (other tasks) will continue to be executed. But you have to remember that the delay will not be precise as the control might not be passed immediately after the time. It will be passed when the scheduler does the switch and there are no tasks with higher priority in the READY state

Comment: Got you..so the delay mentioned is not precise maybe for more precision vTaskDelayUntil() could be used. The point i wanted to understand is clarified that context is restored from where it last stopped. Thank you

Comment: "`vTaskDelay()` is not blocking. The task is put into the BLOCKED state..."  So it *is* blocking.

Comment: @JeremyP Blocking means that the program flow is being blocked - which is not the case here. Like HAL_Delay() which blocks the program flow

Comment: @JeremyP my bad i did not clarify the terminology. What i meant by blocking was putting the task in a blocking state not as blocking in other platforms (wasting cpu cycles doing nothing)...@0___________ is right blocking in rtos doesnt mean blocking flow of the program

Comment: @JeremyP and I clarified it in the answer I believe

Comment: I was thinking in general terms (I don't know anything about freeRTOS). A task that is blocked is one that cannot continue for any reason. A blocking function is one that blocks the task it is in, which waiting for period of time clearly does. On the other hand, if you mean that `vTaskDelay()` doesn't block *everything else* that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I think your definition of "blocking" differs from that generally used in RTOS and is too subtle to be worth mentioning.  It would have generated less "noise" (and confusion) had you omitted it.  I am not sure I understand your distinction in any event I would use the term "blocking" to describe that behaviour, and plenty of other sources do so too, including the FreeRTOS documentation https://www.freertos.org/a00127.html

Answer (score 0):

In a pre-remptive priority based RTOS (including FreeRTOS) context switches occur as a result of the scheduler running.  The scheduler will run on exit from the interrupt context (including but not only the system tick interrupt), or when a call is made to an RTOS function that either pends the current task (yields) or which may change the state of a currently blocked task (pre-empts).

An RTOS delay is an example of a *yielding* function - the task *voluntarily* gives up the CPU and causes the scheduler to run.  Yielding functions include:

- delay
- semaphore take
- message queue receive
- event flag wait
- mutex resource release

Functions that may cause preemption

- semaphore give
- message queue send
- event flag trigger
- mutex resource lock

Delay is distinct in that it appears to have no pre-empt counterpart, but in fact the delay *expiry* (on system tick interrupt) causes pre-emption by the task issuing the the delay.

Some RTOS have a specific *yield* function, essentially equivalent to a zero length delay.  Such a function is useful only when round-robin scheduling of same-priority tasks is supported, since a higher priority task becoming ready will pre-empt, and a lower-priority ready task will not be scheduled on a zero length delay (at least it shouldn't). A yield or zero-delay can be used for *co-operative* multitasking or where time-slicing is supported it allows a thread to voluntarily "give-up" the remainder of its slice.